# Delphi XE2 on Windows 10 can not debug (disconnected session)

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe2

My Delphi XE2 has stopped working giving error "Disconnected session" with the underneath log:

> [20372E20]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugKernel.msgBox (Line 5902,
>   "Debug.pas" + 30) + $0 [19C26EB3]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at
>   DllUnregisterServer + $5037 [19C9B8A8]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function
>   at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $619D0 [19C9B927]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown
>   function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $61A4F [19C9C36D]{bordbk160.dll}
>   Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $62495
>   [19C9C5BD]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv +
>   $626E5 [19CCC3E3]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at
>   @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $9250B [19C39D72]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function
>   at DllUnregisterServer + $17EF6 [19CCCEE2]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown
>   function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $9300A [19CCCBFB]{bordbk160.dll}
>   Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $92D23
>   [19CCCAD6]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv +
>   $92BFE [19CCC19A]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at
>   @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $922C2 [19C9C7FC]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function
>   at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $62924 [19C9CCCE]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown
>   function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $62DF6 [19CBDA44]{bordbk160.dll}
>   Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $83B6C
>   [19C45E88]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv +
>   $BFB0 [19CDF92B]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv
>   + $A5A53 [19CD215A]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $98282 [19CD2AB4]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function
>   at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $98BDC [19CD2043]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown
>   function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $9816B [19CD19A9]{bordbk160.dll}
>   Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $97AD1
>   [19C27CAE]{bordbk160.dll} Unknown function at DllUnregisterServer +
>   $5E32 [20371B1B]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugKernel.CreateProcess
>   (Line 5427, "Debug.pas" + 17) + $63 [2037F6AD]{dbkdebugide160.bpl}
>   Debug.TDebugger.DoCreateProcess (Line 11628, "Debug.pas" + 74) + $3C
>   [2037F820]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugger.CreateProcess (Line
>   11655, "Debug.pas" + 6) + $2F [20380373]{dbkdebugide160.bpl}
>   Debug.TDebugger.Run (Line 12064, "Debug.pas" + 23) + $33
>   [20380DEA]{dbkdebugide160.bpl} Debug.TDebugger.Run (Line 12389,
>   "Debug.pas" + 129) + $43 [2037AFE6]{dbkdebugide160.bpl}
>   Debug.TDebugger.Run (Line 10045, "Debug.pas" + 0) + $2
>   [2078C66D]{coreide160.bpl} DebuggerMgr.TDebuggerMgr.Run (Line 1913,
>   "DebuggerMgr.pas" + 3) + $B [500B5B9B]{rtl160.bpl  }
>   System.Classes.TBasicAction.Execute (Line 13372, "System.Classes.pas"
>   + 3) + $7 [5031B86D]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.ActnList.TContainedAction.Execute (Line 448, "Vcl.ActnList.pas" +
>   8) + $2C [5031C658]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.ActnList.TCustomAction.Execute
>   (Line 1094, "Vcl.ActnList.pas" + 7) + $8 [0041B8D0]{bds.exe     }
>   AppMain.TIDEVCLApplication.UsesProxy (Line 7318, "AppMain.pas" + 0) +
>   $0 [0041B351]{bds.exe     } AppMain..TDebugXPStyleMenuItem (Line 7164,
>   "AppMain.pas" + 0) + $1DC [2073B9F6]{coreide160.bpl}
>   EditorForm.TEditWindow.CMWindowCommand (Line 3133, "EditorForm.pas" +
>   14) + $9 [50332995]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line
>   7204, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6 [503372F3]{vcl160.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9976, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 152)
>   + $6 [5003D50F]{rtl160.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 14790, "System.pas" + 10) + $0 [5003D078]{rtl160.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter
>   (Line 14489, "System.pas" + 4) + $2 [5003CF1C]{rtl160.bpl  }
>   System.TMonitor.CheckOwningThread (Line 14411, "System.pas" + 2) + $0
>   [5003D222]{rtl160.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 14600,
>   "System.pas" + 9) + $7 [5003D25B]{rtl160.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit
>   (Line 14614, "System.pas" + 2) + $7 [50313723]{vcl160.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Graphics.FreeMemoryContexts (Line 7043, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 12) +
>   $8 [50336948]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line
>   9689, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6 [5033695D]{vcl160.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9692, "Vcl.Controls.pas" +
>   6) + $0 [500B6890]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line
>   13878, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0 [503372F3]{vcl160.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9976, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 152)
>   + $6 [5044A021]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc (Line 4344, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 201) + $5 [50336948]{vcl160.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9689, "Vcl.Controls.pas" +
>   3) + $6 [500B6890]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line
>   13878, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0 [50453213]{vcl160.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10164, "Vcl.Forms.pas" +
>   23) + $1 [50453256]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage
>   (Line 10194, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4 [50453595]{vcl160.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10332, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3

I have ignored this problem for a long time using Delphi 2010 and sometimes XE4 instead, but XE2 is/was my main IDE for Windows work so...

Comment: What is X2? Do you mean XE2?  Debugging works fine for me. Identify what is different for you. What has changed.

Comment: Also on Windows 10? Is your XE2 fully patched? I have found some reports on quality central with same problem as me - no solution though

Comment: Just ran into the same problem with Delphi XE2 and Windows10 x64.

Answer (score 2):

> **Windows 8 is not a supported platform for versions of Delphi prior to Delphi XE3.** To get debugger support for 64 bit applications on Windows 8, you must get Delphi XE3. If you are upgrade sensitive, Embarcadero recommends you get Support and Maintenance along with your next purchase. Support and Maintenance guarantees you all updates for 1 year and gets you 3 support incidents in addition.

*Source: http://support.codegear.com/article/42650*

Embarcadero QC Report: 
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=133361

If debugging on Windows 8 is not supported prior to XE3, it's relatively certain that neither is debugging on Windows 10.

Comment: I am using Delphi 10.1.2 Berlin on Windows 10 and tried to debug a 64-Bit DLL with a 64-Bit Host-Application from us. I am getting the "disconnected session"-error too. Is there any known problem with this delphi version?

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).